# How can I reference a pages footer that doesn't have a class or id

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an element style that changes the background-color of a footer but when I try to reference it by using `.footer` but it doesn't work. As shown in the image, the footer has a child with a class name, how could I reference that child's class and then make it shift up to the footer for adding the style.

[image]

Comment: Selector by the tag name comes without `.`: literally `footer`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors

Comment: Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how and why to make [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when add **dot** first of word in CSS, this means that is a class so if you want add CSS attribute to the elements you should write the name of elements without dot like below code

```css
footer{
background-color: #633a82;
color:white;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="class-footer">test footer</div>
<footer>
```